# define foreignkey relation in EF model mvc3

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys

im define foreign key relation at model level something like this :

```
public class CMShoppingEntities : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasOptional(c => c.parentCategory)
                .WithMany(c => c.ChildCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentID);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
}
```

so why do we need or is it required to define foreign key relation at database/table level ..?

Comment: No it's not required but it will help you keep integrity in your data.

Comment: thanks stian for your valuable comment ... but i want to ask one more question will it put extra load on database server or require more space to maintain relationship ?

Comment: Question is bit vague . Are you asking why you need foreign keys in database? or why model foreign keys with EF?

Comment: yes it will be more load. By default SQL server will check wether the foreign key is valid. But thats really nothing to worry about. I always add foreignkeys in my databases as they keep integrity and this will also help you in your code by giving you easy access between entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mapping says that FK relationship exists in a database = EF believes that your database uses referential integrity. If your database don't use it, the mapping and your application will still work until somebody stores data in your database which will violate this expected constraint. Then your application will randomly stop working because of inconsistent data.

So if you want FK relationship in your model use it in database as well.

This problem has few more problems:

- If you expect cascade delete to work. You must use referential constraint in database and configure it for cascade delete as well
- Not specifying relationship in the database works easily only when using code mapping. In case of EDMX you must manually maintain SSDL description so that EF still believes that relationship exists